# Using observer inside dialogfragment causes program crash after the dialog window opens a second time

Tags: java, android, viewmodel

I recently asked this question but it got a bit messy so I thought i comprise all information a little bit better and try again.

I want to share data between a regular fragment and a dialog fragment to achieve this I use a shared view model. As you've seen from the title the software crashes the second time I open the dialog window.

Here is the main fragment that has a single button that when clicked opens up a dialog fragment.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private MainViewModel mViewModel;
    private View fragmentView;
    private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;


    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        return fragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

        sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);

        Button aButton = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        aButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sharedViewModel.setColor("Green");
                NavDirections action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToBlankFragment();
                Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(action);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is the code for the dialog fragment that pops up when i click the button.

```
public class BlankFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private View dialogView;
    private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_fragment, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).
                get(SharedViewModel.class); //gets the shared view model from the associsated fragment.
        MutableLiveData<String> tableColor = sharedViewModel.getColor();
        tableColor.observe(getParentFragment().getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IF I GET HERE TWICE I DIE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

As you've probably seen i used a nav graph to navigate between them.

The shared view model looks like this

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<String> color = new MutableLiveData<>();


    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color.setValue(color);
    }
    public MutableLiveData<String> getColor(){
        return color;
    }

}
```

The error message reads:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.dialogfragmentcrashing, PID: 32620
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
>   object reference
>           at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:121)
>           at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:286)
>           at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:276)
>           at com.example.dialogfragmentcrashing.BlankFragment$1.onChanged(BlankFragment.java:47)
>           at com.example.dialogfragmentcrashing.BlankFragment$1.onChanged(BlankFragment.java:44)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
>           at com.example.dialogfragmentcrashing.SharedViewModel.setColor(SharedViewModel.java:11)
>           at com.example.dialogfragmentcrashing.MainFragment$1.onClick(MainFragment.java:49)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7155)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7124)
>           at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:808)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27370)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:359)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7418)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getParentFragment().getViewLifecycleOwner()` is always the wrong `LifecycleOwner` to use as it is not destroyed when the `DialogFragment` is destroyed. Move all of that code to `onCreate()` and use `this`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).
            get(SharedViewModel.class); //gets the shared view model from the associsated fragment.
    MutableLiveData<String> tableColor = sharedViewModel.getColor();
    tableColor.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IF I GET HERE TWICE I DIE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Omg, thank you! I sat so long with this. and I tried the code above just not in an onCreate method. So If I understand your answer correctly. This works because now "this object" is the LifecycleOwner so it will be destroyed together with the dialog box. Whereas before the observer would go on living since the parent was the owner? Further, I also suppose I could put the same code in public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) So I don't have to create a new onCreate method just for this?

Comment: No, it really does need to be in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use viewBinding and kotlin, try this:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    _binding = FragmentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity()).apply {
        setTitle(R.string.add_title)
        setPositiveButton(R.string.add_dialog_ok, null)
        setNegativeButton(R.string.add_dialog_cancel, null)
        setView(binding.root)
    }

    setupViewModel()

    val dialog = builder.create()
    return dialog
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? = binding.root

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupObservers()
}
```